# What's the best way of understanding opencv's warpperspective and warpaffine?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to transform a static image to give the illusion of it being taken from different angles. It seems like `warpPerspective` and `warpAffine` are the functions I should understand to make this work. However, even after read the OpenCV docs, I'm having difficulty understanding them.

What tutorials/docs should I read that explain them very well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

warpPerspective does a projective transformation or homography:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography

warpAffine does an affine transformation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Abid Rahman, already mentioned a good book. If you want a more theoretical one, [Multiple View Geometry](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Multiple-View-Geometry-Computer-Vision/dp/0521540518/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1339263505&sr=8-1) is considered the bible of these topics.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention the language you use.

1. OpenCV documentation has got diagramatic explanation of these
   functions and that is really good.
2. Apart from that, OpenCV also got a tutorial on this with working C++
   code. : [Affine Transformations](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html#warp-affine)

   ( If you use Python, find it here : [Affine Transform](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV2-Python/blob/master/Official_Tutorial_Python_Codes/3_imgproc/geometric_transform.py))
3. And Gary Bradsky's book "Learning OpenCV" has got a good explanation
   of this, if you like, on page 163. You can read it from "[Google
   Books](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=learning%20opencv&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RYbTT8r6FIrqrQeptYj8Dw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=learning%20opencv&f=false)"